# Set different colors for tick labels?

Tags: graphics, ticks

Is it possible to set different colors for individual ticks? I have a few differently colored arrows and I'd like to show their coordinates in different colors.
Here, the two ticks on the X-axis represent X coordinates of the green and red arrow, can I make them green and red respectively?
[image: Here, the two ticks on the X-axis represent X coordinates of the green and red arrow, can I make them green and red respectively?]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the documentation for [`Ticks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ticks):

[image]

So, here is a graphic with red and blue ticks, and green and orange tick labels:

```
Graphics[
    {},
    Axes->True,
    Ticks->{
        {{.2, Style["1",Green], {.02,.02}, Red}, {.8,Style["2",Orange],{.02,.02},Blue}},
        None
    }
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know about the Style[] function.

Comment: Is there a way to move labels to the opposite sides of the axes? E.g. move a label on Y-axis placed to the left of the axis to the right side. Some of my labels are overlapping with each other or the arrows.

Comment: I don't think it's possible using the [`Ticks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ticks) option without some major hackery. On the other hand, you could just use a [`Text`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Text) primitive, e.g. `Graphics[{Text["text", Offset[{0, 15}, {.1, 0}]]}, Axes -> True, 
 Ticks -> {{{.1, ""}, {.5, "foo"}}, None}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]`